# How are reads counted for nested documents in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

For instance does retrieving a document which is in the sub collection of another document count as 1 read or 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A get of a document always costs one read.  It doesn't matter if it's nested under any other documents.  The other parent documents are not read.